# 3 columns passed, passed data had 50 columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the average price of 50 items and when I do this code I get an error saying 3 columns passed, passed data had 50 columns. I only need the three columns for purchase date, title, and price. Here's the code

```
import pandas as pd
items = results.findAll("li")
rows = []
page_source = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
for item in items: 
    titleElement = item.find("h3", {"class": "s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags"})
    priceElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
    dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "POSITIVE"})
    if titleElement and priceElement and dateElement:
        row = [dateElement.text, titleElement.text, priceElement.text]
        rows.append(rows)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=["Purchase Date", "Title", "Price"])
df
```

Comment: `rows` has 50 columns of data, but you are only passing 3 column labels, so there is a length mismatch between the data you are reading in and the number of columns you are naming.

Comment: @DavidErickson how can I change my code so that rows has the appropriate number of rows (50) and columns has the appropriate number of columns (3)?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the entire rows, not the individual row.  Once you fix that, it will likely work.  Note that .from_records is optional, and specifying columns= is optional, so if the code below does not fix the problem, omit columns= and see what you are getting.

```
import pandas as pd
items = results.findAll("li")
rows = []
page_source = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
for item in items: 
    titleElement = item.find("h3", {"class": "s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags"})
    priceElement = item.find("span", {"class": "s-item__price"})
    dateElement = item.find("span", {"class": "POSITIVE"})
    if titleElement and priceElement and dateElement:
        row = [dateElement.text, titleElement.text, priceElement.text]
        # rows.append(rows)   # this appends all of rows to itself
        rows.append(row)      # append only the 1 additional row
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Purchase Date", "Title", "Price"])

# or if that is still failing:
# df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```